# python-mysqldb insert image int value error

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

just trying to take a picture with raspberry pi and inserting actual datetime and picture into mysql db... I've tried to insert just the datetime... thats fine. but I get an error inserting the image...

```
          image = open(picPath+filename, 'r')
            pic = image.read()
            mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host="local", user="root", passwd="bla", db="sexyimages")
            cur = mysql.cursor()
            sql = ("insert into test(SampleTime, picture) values(%s, %s)")
            cur.execute(sql, (jetzt, pic))
            mysql.commit()
```

Warning: Incorrect integer value: '????c?Exif' for column 'picture' at row 1
  cur.execute(sql, (jetzt, pic))

anyone an idea?

oh ya using python-mysqldb

cheeers

Comment: no its declared as mediumblob....

Comment: ah, you might try changing the file opening mode from `'r'` to `'rb'`

Comment: with 'rb'
raspistill -v -o/home/pi/webcam/webcam-2014-11-14_20:05:53.jpg
script.sh:51: Warning: Incorrect integer value: '????c?Exif' for column 'picture' at row 1
  cur.execute(sql, (jetzt, pic))
with 'r' the same

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](http://ashamrad.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-insert-blob-into-mysql-in-python.html) I found that you have to close the file pointer first and escape the string using the `MySQL.escape_string` method. Try this:

```
image = open(picPath+filename)
pic = image.read()
image.close()

mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host="local", user="root", passwd="bla", db="sexyimages")
cur = mysql.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into test SET SampleTime='%s', picture='%s'") %(jetzt, MySQLdb.escape_string(pic))

mysql.commit()
```

Comment: raspistill -v -o/home/pi/webcam/webcam-2014-11-14_20:59:08.jpg
script.sh:52: Warning: Incorrect integer value: '????d\0Exif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\\0\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0
                                                                                                                   \0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\n\0\0\0?\Z\0\0\0\' for column 'picture' at row 1
  cur.execute(sql, (jetzt, MySQLdb.escape_string(pic)))

:( still not the right cmd

Comment: Edited answer. Added quotation marks around the values to insert.

Comment: What do you get when you `print pic`

Comment: a lot of undefined wild text. (?? ?S?????@Xm@?ʢ??????4$o-w63???V]?Il?RnQ?q??9??f%?????n?? ??$??8?9;???.@2?L???p
                                                                                ??U[p

a??^???G???Z?چ???I__????{?Ryc? ̓U#{.?yS?1??d88??T?v?,?~??h???<?!?=??n
J`?y???J?{UD????H?!N?ۂ???)D??՛????ke7i;4??Kw?????Ml_????'r0???Y?e!?$/Ur?WG?z??m?B?ѐ$7F%?J??Tn??
     ~\
       ?%??S????@?*??P??\j8?*8f?

Comment: Edited : I corrected my code again. The variable name was supposed to be `pic`. I had `MYpic` there instead.

Comment: I regonized that already... so we've got the pic. I gets read corretly, from what the output looks like. Its just not getting uploaded right...